# How does Hellboy put his coat on over the Right Hand of Doom?

Tags: comics, hellboy

I don't know why this just occured to me, but I was looking at a picture of Hellboy in his typical trench coat, and he has the right sleeve rolled up to accommodate the Right Hand of Doom, but how does he get his arm into the coat in the first place?

[image]

(EDIT: I've updated the question with the picture that got me thinking about this.)

Is this ever shown?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "[Hellboy II: Art of the Movie](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593079648)" artbook shows that Hellboy has self-customised his sleeves with an extra set of buckles.

[image]

and this set-photo from Hellboy (2004) has a better angle on the buckles

[image]

Comment: Well there you go!  I stand corrected.

Comment: @JaneS - My advantage is that I asked myself the question a few months ago, then answered it during the film

Comment: I admit I haven't seen the movie for a couple of years, and it didn't cross my radar at the time.  Well answered, sir! :)

Comment: Nice one :) It's different from the comic book picture I posted, but it's a good answer.

Answer (score 9):

### Because his trenchcoat has really big sleeves!

[image: HellBoy sleeves]

As you can see here, the sleeves have plenty of room for his "normal" hand.  In fact, it's very loose fitting.  There appears to be room for him to slip it over his Right Hand of Doom without too much trouble.

I would assume he pulls it back from his Right Hand of Doom for effect, and possibly comfort, but it does appear big enough to accommodate putting it on.

Comment: Haha,  good  answer!

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Thanks!  I actually just went to find a picture to check what OP meant, then I saw this and thought, "Hang on, that's a _big_ sleeve!" :D

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Good, but wrong. Them sleeves might be big, but they still need [extra buckles](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/120770/20774) :-)